# How can I get the "Welcome Channel" chosen in the Discord guild config?

Tags: discord.js

I want to get the channel.id of the "Welcome channel" present in the Discord guild configuration.

Here is what the option look like : [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPS9J.png)

I just want to retrieve the channel selected in that dropbox. Do you have any idea how can I get it ? I don't find anything useful inside the documentation...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Guild#systemChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=systemChannel) or [Guild#systemChannelID](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=systemChannelID) for that, this also matched up with the English Discord Client.

[image: Image of the English Discord Client naming it systemChannel too]

Comment: It's working ! The name of the property is a little misleading. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually u have a property to get that, called `.systemChannel` [watch this](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=systemChannel).

Comment: But this property is deprecated ?

Comment: Did they added something to replace it ? Or do we need to make without it ?

Comment: For now u can use that property, in future we will see.

Comment: Whoops, mistyped.